# Quelles étiquettes utiliser? What should our tags be?

Tags: discussion, tags

Une des [7 questions essentielles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/): quelles étiquettes utiliser ?

---

One of the [7 essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/): what should our tags be?

Comment: Related: [Should question tags be in English or French? Or both?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/59)

Answer (score 10):

Je propose de nous inspirer fortement des étiquettes du site [Langue et usage de l'anglais (ELU)](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) — en les traduisant en français. Le sujet est difficile à classifier, et je trouve que ELU a particulièrement bien réussi son choix d'étiquettes. Ci-dessous, je présente les 100 étiquettes les plus utilisées sur ELU et une proposition de traduction. De plus, pour faciliter l'abord aux visiteurs anglophones, des [synonymes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) peuvent être mis en place, afin que le logiciel traduise silencieusement les noms d'étiquettes existantes de l'anglais vers le français.

---

I suggest that we by and large follow the tags of [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags). The subject matter is difficult to classify, and I find that EL&U has had remarkable success with its choice of tags. Below, I've copied the 100 most used tags on EL&U with a translation proposal. Furthermore, to ease things for English-speaking visitors, a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) can be set up (you type the English name, and the software silently translates it to the French name).

---

```
meaning               sens
word-choice           choix-de-mot
grammar               grammaire
etymology             etymologie
single-word-requests  demande-de-mot
phrases               expressions
grammaticality        grammaticalite
differences           differences
idioms                idiomes
verbs                 verbes
pronunciation         prononciation
vocabulary            vocabulaire
meaning-in-context    sens-dans-le-contexte
grammatical-number    nombre-grammatical
prepositions          prepositions
nouns                 noms
punctuation           ponctuation
american-english      france
adjectives            adjectifs
word-usage            usage
british-english       quebec (belgique, suisse, …)
synonyms              synonymes
expressions           expressions (?!)
spelling              orthographe
slang                 argot
pronouns              pronoms
history               histoire
terminology           terminologie
adverbs               adverbes
writing               ecriture
articles              articles
sentence              phrase
word-order            ordre-des-mots
possessive            possessifs
tense                 temps-grammatical
dialects              dialectes
phrase-requests       demande-d-expression
abbreviations         abreviations
capitalization        majuscules
conjunctions          conjonctions
antonyms              antonymes
offensive-language    vulgarite
comma                 virgule
formality             formalite
common-expressions    expressions-courantes
writing-style         style
politeness            politesse
syntax                syntaxe
names                 noms
numbers               nombres
connotation           connotation
past-tense            passe
questions             questions
indefinite-article    article-indefini
colloquial            langage-familier
quotes                guillemets + citations
hyphen                trait-d-union = tiret
contractions          -
apostrophe            apostrophe
acronyms              acronymes
loan-words            emprunts
suffix                suffixes
modal-verbs           auxiliaires
proper-nouns          noms-propres
conversation          oral
phrasal-verbs         -
learning              apprentissage
negation              negation
sentence-patterns     motifs
definite-article      article-defini
gender                genre
jargon                jargon
linguistics           linguistique
semantics             semantique
verb-agreement        accords
prefixes              prefixes
email                 courriel = e-mail
technical             technique
personal-pronouns     pronoms-personnels
translation           traduction
confusables           confusions
speech                oral (?)
saying                proverbe
part-of-speech        nature
ambiguity             ambiguite (= confusions ?)
style                 style (?)
rules                 regles
accent                accent
time                  temps
language-evolution    evolution
mathematics           mathematiques
infinitive            infinitif
comparative           comparaisons
morphology            morphologie
hypernyms             hypernymes
compounds             mots-composes
lyrics                chansons
list-request          liste
analogy               analogie
programming           programmation
```

Comment: Pourquoi pas 'francais-de-france', 'francais-de-belgique', 'francais-de-quebec' etc. en place de 'france', 'belgique', 'quebec', etc.?

Comment: @Jez Je trouve `francais-de-france` (etc) long et redondant, mais pourquoi pas.

Comment: @Gilles: Il est suffisant de taper "france" et "francais-de-france" va etre suggere automatiquement.

Comment: @thei En général, sur Stack Exchange, on évite d'inclure le nom du site dans les étiquettes. On sait bien qu'on ne va pas parler de l'`allemand-de-suisse` ici. Cela dit, c'est vrai que le site anglophone utilise `american-english`, etc.

Comment: I could just revise it, but by curiosity - why are the English and French sections mixed into each other, rather than separate? The last sentences of each paragraph seem to have been swapped.

Comment: @Grace I'm confused about which language to speak, just like a certain SE employee is confused about hir gender. (No, it's just because I goofed when editing the post.)

Answer (score 3):

Pourquoi certains tags seraient-ils au pluriel, et certains au singulier?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags)'s the [english.se] mini-debate on the topic. I seem to recall other discussions on some meta (not [metase], I think), which I can't find now.

Comment: There are some in the link you provided (which is a good starting point by itself anyway)

Answer (score 2):

On ferait bien de distinguer [traduction-francais-anglais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traduction-francais-anglais) et [traduction-anglais-francais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traduction-anglais-francais) dès maintenant.

(Sans cédille dans les tags, malheureusement.)

Comment: Personnellement je préfèrerais en-fr et fr-en...

Comment: @Benjol. J'ai vu des 'traduction-en-fr' et 'traduction-fr-en' apparaître. Ça me paraît plutôt pas mal. Par contre, je trouve que 'en-fr' et 'fr-en' ne sont pas assez descriptifs.

Comment: Je propose d'avoir un tag `traduction`, et puis un tag pour chaque langue reconnue pour décrire la langue source du traduction (`anglais`, `allemand`, `neerlandais`, etc.).  On met les deux tags sur les questions de traduction.  Ce mécanisme est plus flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Une autre proposition pour les tags liés à la traduction, en séparant la nature de la traduction de la langue considérée :

- [version](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version) : traduction de *x* au français
- [theme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme) : traduction du français à *x*

Que l'on pourra combiner à des tags qui peuvent être utilisés pour indiquer une référence à une certaine langue dans la question :

- [anglais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglais) : la question fait référence à un mot, une expression, ou un texte en anglais.
- [allemand](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allemand) : la question fait référence à un mot, une expression, ou un texte en allemand.
- [espagnol](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espagnol) : la question fait référence à un mot, une expression, ou un texte en espagnol.
- etc…

Ces tags ne signifient **pas** que la question est posée dans cette langue.
Mais peut-être que c'est trop confus?

(sorry not enough time for translation)

Comment: D'accord, mais pouvez-vous changer les tags `en`, `de`, etc... à `anglais`, `allemand`, etc...?

Comment: @Jez. C'est fait. "en" et "de" provoquaient déjà un clash avec les mots respectifs. « Peux-[tu](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213) » ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Pourrait-on avoir [fle](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fle) à l'instar de  [esl](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esl) sur EL&U ?

---

Could we have [fle](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fle) in the same way EL&U has [esl](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esl)?

Comment: We can, all it takes is for someone to add it to the relevant questions. I don't think `fle` is the right tag name (could be a synonym), however, because it's an obscure abbreviation, not well-known outside language teachers. `francais-langue-etrangere` (it just fits)?