# Tag descriptions and synonyms / Bien démarrer notre système d'étiquettes

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We now have reached the point where a few users (and many more to come) have enough rep to approve tag edits, and suggest synonyms. The latter, in particular, is very important to do early in the site’s life to avoid having to perform a massive retagging later on.

Thus, I would like to encourage everyone to visit the [tags page](https://french.stackexchange.com/tags) and the pages of the top tags, suggest synonyms and vote on them.

---

Maintenant que nous avons des utilisateurs qui ont le droit de suggérer des synonymes d'étiquettes, de les voter, d'approuver des descriptions pour les différentes étiquettes, je suggère que nous faisions tous un effort pour passer un peu de temps à développer cette partie important de la vie du site. Le faire maintenant nous évitera d'avoir à ré-étiquetter massivement les questions plus tard.

J'encourage chacun à regarder régulièrement la [page des étiquettes](https://french.stackexchange.com/tags) et les pages des étiquettes les plus courues, à suggérer des synonymes et à voter sur les synonymes proposés.

Answer (score 2):

There is a already a thread [What should our tags be?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6), in which I suggest to draw inspiration from the tags on [english.se], which we have been doing so far. Please [maintain and expand the list of translations](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/quelles-etiquettes-utiliser-what-should-our-tags-be/8#8) as our tag usage evolves.

---

Je rappelle le fil [Quelles étiquettes utiliser ? What should our tags be?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6) dans lequel je propose de s'inspirer des tags d'[english.se], ce qui a été fait jusqu'à présent. Merci de [maintenir et étendre la liste de traductions](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/quelles-etiquettes-utiliser-what-should-our-tags-be/8#8) au fil de l'évolution des usages.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>I tried to suggest "grammaire" as a synonym for "grammar" but couldn't because apparently 5 questions were needed with that tag (or maybe it was a requirement on me, I'm not sure).</strike>

Funny thing is both questions with "grammar" were mine... I retagged one as it was purely in French, but I'd still like to make the synonym.

Any links on how it works? I'm lazy.

The error I get is:

> Sorry, creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this

Also, I have no clue where to approve current suggestions either. I'm starting to think I also need the "edit tag wiki" privilege, is that correct?

Never mind, I'm an idiot.