# Should our site have the tag: 'nominalization'? Notre site, devrait-il inclure le tag « nominalisation » ?

Tags: discussion, tags

### Nominalization

I was browsing our tag section and saw that there was no tag for *nominalization*.  In my opinion, this is an important subject in French grammar.  For me it was a large part of my intermediate French studies during university.

I have never created a tag before, but I feel that our site should have this one.  I know how to create a tag so I would like to discuss the following before I do so:

1. **In your opinion, should the site have the tag '*nominalization*'?**
2. **If yes, what is the best way to create it?** For example, should I just come up with a question about it and ask it, or should I ask a question and answer it myself?  Should the question be specific about one verb or group of verbs, or perhaps about the concept of nominalization itself?

---

### Nominalisation

J'ai parcouru les tags de notre site et j'ai remarqué qu'il n'y a pas de tag : « nominalisation ».  Selon moi, nominalisation est un sujet important de la grammaire française.  Pour moi, elle était un grand aspect pendant que je suivais les cours de niveau intermédiaire à l'université.

Je n'ai jamais créé un nouveau tag, mais je suis sûr que notre site devrait inclure « nominalisation ».  Je sais comment on crée un tag, mais je voudrais que nous discutions des suivants avant que je le fasse :

1. **Selon vous, le site, devrait-il inclure cette tag : '*nominalisation*' ?**
2. **Si oui, comment devrais-je le créer ?**  Par exemple, devrais-je poser une question au sujet de nominalisation? Peut-être que je devrais poser une question et répondre à la question moi-même ?  Cette question, devrait-elle être très spécifique, ou plus générale (au sujet de la nominalisation elle-même) ?

Comment: Why are these questions being written in French and English? [I'm merely inquiring.]

Answer (score 4):

If you have enough reputation (150), you can create any tag you want when asking a question, or retagging an existing question. Assigning a tag that hadn't been used so far effectively creates the tag.

In my view, tags are efficient if they are widely used. Creating a single question with that tag, or retagging a single question, won't make it any more used that it currently is. So, unless we intend to perform a massive retagging (which is somewhat disruptive because it bumps questions up on the front page), I don't think creating the tag will achieve anything. It's an important concept, but I don't think people will spontaneously tag questions with this term.

Answer (score 3):

A tag is created when someone posts or retags a question to use it. There are no tags with no questions. Any user with the [“create tags” privilege](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (requiring 150 reputation while the site is in beta) can create a tag (users without the privilege have to make do with the existing tags).

Do not ask a question in order to create a tag. Ask a question because you want to know the answer.

If you're unsure whether a tag is a good idea or how to name it, starting a discussion on meta is the right thing.

We've used [the tags of English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) as a [basis](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/quelles-etiquettes-utiliser-what-should-our-tags-be) for our tags (though the sites have evolved independently since then). I see no corresponding tag on EL&U.

A tag for nominalization seems overspecific to me. The point of a tag is that people can subscribe to it or ignore it, or that it helps when searching for a question on a given topic. Is there really a need to search for questions about nominalization?

I'd lean at least for a more general tag covering the use of a word with an unusual part of speech (such as [this question about using a noun as a verb](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/how-would-i-convert-an-arbitrary-noun-to-a-verb)). I wouldn't know how to name it, however, and a tag is only useful if most users would think of using that tag name.

---

Une étiquette est créée lorsque quelqu'un crée une question qui la porte ou l'ajoute en éditant une question. Il n'y a pas d'étiquettes vierges de questions. Tout utilisateur bénéficiant du [privilège « *create tags* »](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (réputation minimale de 150 tant que le site est en bêta) peut créer une étiquette, les autres devant se contenter des étiquettes existantes.

Ne posez pas une question juste pour créer une étiquette. Posez une question si vous voulez connaître la réponse.

En cas de doute sur le bien fondé ou le nom idéal pour une étiquette, la bonne chose à faire est d'initier une discussion sur le site méta.

Nous nous sommes [basés](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/quelles-etiquettes-utiliser-what-should-our-tags-be) sur les [étiquettes de English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags). Je ne vois pas d'étiquette qui pourrait correspondre sur EL&U.

Une étiquette consacrée à la nominalisation me paraît trop spécifique. Le but d'une étiquette est qu'on peut y souscrire ou au contraire l'ignorer, ou qu'elle est utile pour chercher des questions sur un sujet donné. A-t-on vraiment besoin de chercher les questions qui portent spécifiquement sur la nominalisation ?

Je pencherais au moins pour une étiquette plus générale, qui couvrirait toute utilisation d'un mot avec une nature inhabituelle (comme par exemple [cette question sur la verbalisation](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/how-would-i-convert-an-arbitrary-noun-to-a-verb)). Cependant, je ne saurais pas comment nommer cette étiquette, et une étiquette n'est utile que si l'on peut espérer qu'elle viendra à l'esprit de la plupart des gens.